# UIImage UIImageJPEGRepresentation safe to UIImage

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, jpeg, representation

I need to perform UIImageJPEGRepresentation method and after that save it NOT to file, I need to save it to UIImage. Help please..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have no idea why you are wanting to go from a UIImage to jpeg data and then right back to a UIImage, but `[UIImage imageWithData:jpegdata]` should do it.

Comment: Ok, If somebody interesting it question.. there is solution

     NSData *tempData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
    UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageWithData:tempData];

Comment: @mazder: We're all wondering why you want to do that, instead of just using `image` directly.

Comment: @LightNight, that's too many steps.  The first part could be stated as `NSData *tempData = UIIMgePNGRepresentation(image);` -- no need for the `dataWithData` part.  Otherwise, yes, your comment will turn a UIImage into an NSData and back.

Answer (score 8):

you can use this:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(uiimageObject,1.0);

UIImage *imageObj = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Answer (score 0):

Eh? `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` converts an **image** to JPEG data...

Comment: I Know, after that I need to save result to UIImage not to local directory.